# jquery clone function width a addClass nested

Tags: jquery, clone

I'm having problem to **select** my option when the div has been cloned.

Once cloned I want to be able to select the options and give a selected class. So each cloned div has e selected option.

Please check my demo and try to clone.

http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/60/

**Jquery**

```
var cloneCount = 0;
$("#add-address").click(function() {

    $("#to-add-address").clone()
        .attr("id", "to-add-address_Clone" + cloneCount)
        .insertAfter("#to-add-address");
    $("#clone", "#to-add-address_Clone" + cloneCount)
        .attr("id", "clone_Clone" + cloneCount);
    cloneCount++;

    $('.options li a').bind('click',function () {
            $('.options li a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>    
    <li id="to-add-address" class="outerDiv address" >
        <div id="clone">
            <label><input type="text" value="Address"><span class="input-edit"></span></label>
            <label><input type="text" value="Address 2"><span class="input-edit"></span></label>
            <label><input type="text" value="Town"><span class="input-edit"></span></label>
            <label><input type="text" value="Contry"><span class="input-edit"></span></label>
            <label><input type="text" value="Post Code"><span class="input-edit"></span></label>

            <ul class="options">
                <li class="home"><a href="javascript:void(0);">home</a></li>
                <li class="work"><a href="javascript:void(0);">work</a></li>
                <li class="other"><a href="javascript:void(0);">other</a></li>
                <li class="delete"><a href="javascript:void(0);">delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>


<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add-address">clone</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it to this to only affect the elements within that clone:

```
$(this).closest(".options").find('li a').removeClass('selected');
```

---

Additionally, you are re-binding click each time causing the number of listeners on each element to increase with every clone, instead use event delegation:

```
    $(document).on("click", '.options li a',function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest(".options").find('li a').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');
    });
```

if your real code has a common parent, replace `document` with the appropriate selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/61/

Comment: You can again use `closest` to find the nearest ancestor with a given selector.  Perhaps `$(this).closest(".outerDiv").remove()`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/69/ on this fiddle the "delete" is removing all the divs, and I'm not able to clone any more. any idea?

Comment: Because you have it set to run whenever any link is clicked, not just the delete link.  AND your clone depends on that first one being there, if you delete it clone wont' work anymore.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/73/ thanks for your advises, is now working but how can I keep just one div?